# Limit $\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{1}{1+e^{1/x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have a small question about evaluating $$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{1}{1+e^{1/x}}$$

If I look at $e^{1/x}$, as $x\to 0^-$, it approaches $\frac{1}{-\infty}$.

How does $$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{1}{1+e^{1/x}}=1?$$

Some insight would be great.
Thanks!

Comment: $\lim_{t\to-\infty}e^t=0$

Comment: Just to point out, a positive value raised to an exponent can never give a negative value.

Comment: @KM101 just edited that.

Comment: “Approaches $\frac{1}{-\infty}$” is a different way to say that the limit is $0$ (with a bit more information that in this case is irrelevant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that :

$$\lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{1}{1+\exp(1/x)} = \frac{1}{\lim_{x \to 0^-} (1+\exp(1/x))}= \frac{1}{1+\lim_{x \to 0^-}\exp(1/x)}$$

Now, since $x \to 0^-$, this means it approaches zero by the negative side, which yields that :

$$\lim_{x \to 0^-} \exp(1/x) = \lim_{x\to 0^-} \exp(\lim_{x \to 0^-} 1/x) = \exp(-\infty) = 0$$

It is also easy to spot that, using the substitution $t = 1/x$ and noting that when $x \to 0^- \Rightarrow t \to -\infty$.

Thus, finally :

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{1}{1+e^\frac{1}{x}} = 1$$

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac1x=-\infty$.

So that $\lim_{x\to0^-}e^{\frac1x}=\lim_{y\to-\infty}e^{y}=\lim_{z\to+\infty}e^{-z}=\lim_{z\to+\infty}\frac1{e^z}=0$.

So that $\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac1{1+e^{\frac1x}}=\frac1{1+0}=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^-}e^{\frac1x}=e^{\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac1x}=e^{-\infty}=0$,$$\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac1{1+e^{\frac1x}}=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

We have that $\frac1x \to -\infty$ then by $y=-\frac1x \to \infty$ we have

$$\frac{1}{1+e^\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{1}{1+e^{-y}}\to 1$$

since $e^{-y}=\frac1 {e^y}\to 0$.