# Solving limit problems using L'hopital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits

As a part of the solution to a problem, the following was provided: $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } \left[ {\ln z} \right] = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } \frac{{{{\bf{e}}^x} + 1}}{{{{\bf{e}}^x} + x}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } \frac{{{{\bf{e}}^x}}}{{{{\bf{e}}^x} + 1}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } \frac{{{{\bf{e}}^x}}}{{{{\bf{e}}^x}}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to \infty } \left( 1 \right) = 1$$
My question is: How is the simplification after the third step allowed. Was L'hopital's rule used again?

Comment: Yes, since it ends up in the indeterminate form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.

Comment: $\dfrac {e^x}{e^x+1}=\dfrac 1{1+e^{-x}}$

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3011429/limit-lim-x-to-0-frac11e1-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. When we attempt to evaluate $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x}{e^x+1}$, we get $\frac∞∞$, which means we can apply L'Hopital's rule again to get $\lim_{x→∞} \frac{e^x}{e^x}$.

Comment: Thank you! On this site you can use mathjax to make the mathematics easier to use

Comment: Thank you very much. I will make sure to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since it also will be an indeterminate form of the form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ so it can be used.